# How can I debug a native C++ dll that supports CLR

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Ever since I added Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) for my project I 
have been having so much trouble getting information from the code I am 
debugging in C++.  I had to enable this support so that I could load a 
.NET *dll in the C++ code for my project.  I am not sure why this is 
happening, but I need to be able to indentify what is causing this.

[image: Property Pages]

The way I debug is that I attach to a java process that loads my C++ code which 
is in a dll. A *pdb file for that *dll is in the same directory where the *dll is
loaded from.

I keep getting this 'undefined value' for various primitive types I could easilly
view before. Is there some easy tutorial on how to get debugging information correctly
loaded onto visual studio 2010.

Comment: Java + native + CLR all in one process?  Risktaker!

Comment: I never have issues with this. Perhaps you're building with pdb ***and*** optimizations?

Comment: @MooingDuck: I have no choice.